# Can mysqldump do one query per line?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible for mysqldump to dump one query per line?

For example, it currently dumps a CREATE TABLE expressions like so:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `post`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `comment_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `about` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_visit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `perm_mod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `perm_admin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vote_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `voted_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forgot_key` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cookie_key` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

Instead, I want it to dump like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `post`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`title` varchar(160) NOT NULL,`slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`url` varchar(600) NOT NULL,`domain` varchar(90) NOT NULL,`author` int(11) NOT NULL,`description` text,`category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`score` int(11) NOT NULL,`ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`created` datetime NOT NULL,`comment_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',PRIMARY KEY (`id`),UNIQUE KEY `uc_slug` (`slug`) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`login` varchar(12) NOT NULL,`password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,`email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,`about` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,`last_visit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,`ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`created` datetime NOT NULL,`perm_mod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`perm_admin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`post_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`comment_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`vote_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`voted_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`forgot_key` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,`cookie_key` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

I have been going through the args for mysqldump, and can't find anything that would do this

Comment: Needs to be one line for mysql_query(); line-by-line processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is no command-line switch to achieve this. Instead I recommend you to do the dump normally and then use a good text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to open dump file.

First select block to convert to single line, then select menu option of the folowing image.

[image: Unwrap Text]

This is the result (repeat for every block to convert to single line):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that will work, a little tedious but thankfully my dump is only 10 or so tables

Answer (score 1):

I had similar task - to format mysqldump output file to be mysql init_file option compatible. Here is the solution:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/THISISUNIQUESTRING/g' | sed -e 's/;THISISUNIQUESTRING/;\n/g' | sed -e 's/THISISUNIQUESTRING//g'
```

This replaces all newline chars with a weird string that is not present in the file. Next sed replaces the combination of this string and semicolon with semicolon and newline char. This is needed because table data can contain string values that include ";", so straighforward removal of all newline chars and adding them after semicolons is not universal. 
After that remaining weird strings are just removed from the text.

Btw, I was running mysqldump with `--comments=false` parameter, as comments are not allowed for "init_file" thing as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want individual queries the most pragmatic solution in my book would be to use the built-in functionality of mysqldump. The `--skip-extended-insert` flag is what you want, it is not clear in the documentation but it gives you the dump format you want.